# How to get the list of logged persons in JSF application?

Tags: jsf, session, logging

in my jsf application i have an entity "Person" which can have as attribute a list of Person :

```
List<Person> listFriends;
```

when a user is logged,i store informations in a session Bean.
And  i want to get the list of  friends who are also logged.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store information within bean Application Scoped.

@ApplicationScoped Shared state across all users' interactions with a web application

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can i update this bean when a user leave my web application without logout? i tried with a HttpSessionListener but i'm not sure it works